# netbeans regex to find a string inside bracket

Tags: regex, netbeans

I have a string to find: [general_options] and used this exp: `(\[.*])` in netbeans

However it's finding whole [....] string with bracket and I need only what is inside: general_options, how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you change your capturing group

```
\[(.*)]
```

and get your result from the capturing group 1 (assuming this is the only one)

OR you use [lookehind and lookahead assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) (if they are supported)

```
(?<=\[).*(?=])
```

Comment: however I need to replace it with 'general_options' '$1' is not working

Comment: `$1` is the content from capturing group 1. The second regex doesn't have a capturing group. ==> Try `$0` or change the regex to `(?<=\[)(.*)(?=])`.